# Submit/Post PDF Form to Spring Controller

Tags: java, apache, spring-mvc, pdfbox

I am using `Apache PDF Box API` to process PDF Form data.

Using **Main Method**, and reading a pdf file from specific location, it is working fine.

Now i want to provide some sort of 'submit button', in the `PDF` Form itself, and when the user connects to the server, and clicks on 'submit button', the request should come to by `Spring MVC Controller`.

How to go about integrating `PDF Form` submit button with Spring `Controller`, is there some sort of action mapping that i can provide in PDF form, similar to as we do in `JSP` page.

Comment: please post your jsp